# Flutter webview connection refused in web

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I want to build an app with WebView on `Android`, `IOS` and `Web`.

so I download [this sample](https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx)

It works when I load "https://flutter.dev"
[image]

But when I change the url to "https://www.google.com" , the web will come the error connection refused in web.

Emulator still works.
[image]
How to solve it

In addition, do you have any recommendations library build WebView on `Android`, `IOS` and `Web`?

I tried several popular ones but they were all so difficult to use.

Comment: Hi @GHH, did you find the solution? I am in the same situation. If you could find the solution, I would love to be assisted.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Github issue/documentation](https://github.com/adrianflutur/webviewx/issues/27):

> 3. Normal URLs which do not support iframe embedding (such as https://google.com, you need to use `SourceType.urlBypass` for this).

```dart
 webviewController.loadContent(
                'https://google.com',
                SourceType.urlBypass,
              );
```

Complete example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webviewx/webviewx.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyWebViewPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWebViewPageState createState() => _MyWebViewPageState();
}

class _MyWebViewPageState extends State<MyWebViewPage> {
  late WebViewXController webviewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebViewX Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          WebViewX(
            initialContent: 'https://example.com',
            // initialSourceType: SourceType.,
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) => webviewController = controller,
            onWebResourceError: (error) {
              print('WebViewX Error: ${error.errorCode}, ${error.description}');
            },
            // ... other options

            width: 400,
            height: 400,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Load a URL when the button is pressed
              webviewController.loadContent(
                'https://google.com',
                SourceType.urlBypass,
              );
            },
            child: Text('Load Google Website'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Go back in the webview's history
              webviewController.goBack();
            },
            child: Text('Go Back'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Go forward in the webview's history
              webviewController.goForward();
            },
            child: Text('Go Forward'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using `iFrameElement` to launch the URL in a dialog on the web platform,

like this: 
` final IFrameElement iFrameElement = IFrameElement()
        ..src = url
        ..attributes['sourceType'] = 'urlBypass'
        ..style.border = 'none'
        ..style.width = '100%'
        ..style.height = '100%'; `

Still, I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx

Use https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

It's official library

Use like this ->

[image]

For webview use iFrameElement but it will only work if CORS policy is enabled

Comment: will this `webview_flutter` support the web platform?

Comment: For webview use iFrameElement but it will only work if CORS policy is enabled